# Abita Andygator Clone (helles doppelbock)

Tags: all-grain, recipe, brewing, clone-recipe

I had this beer over the weekend and really enjoyed it and I would love to brew an all grain clone of it myself. Is anyone familiar with this beer? if so does anyone know of a recipe that would come close. The ABV is 8%.

Comment: Are you able to ferment at lager temperatures at all?

Comment: Clone recipe [posted here](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showpost.php?p=4539348&postcount=13) don't know how legal it was for them to post, and how legal for me would be to re-post here.

Comment: Yes I have a freezer with a temp cont. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone recipe [posted here](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showpost.php?p=4539348&postcount=13) don't know how legal it was for them to post, and how legal for me would be to re-post here.

[Manufacturer's site](https://abita.com/brews/our_brews/andygator) gives you ingredients:

- pilsner malt,
- German lager yeast,
- German Perle hops

It also gives you parameters to target, for use with software like [BrewTarget](http://www.brewtarget.org/):

- ABV 8.0%
- IBU 25
- Color 8 SRM

BYO recipe follows these pretty good, with pilsner malt and  pilsner malt extracts. For all grain, you can just use all pilsner malt. They also hop with Perle only, at traditional 60', 30' and 5'.

And use soft water - it seems that's what Abita is using.

Comment: I use WPL833 for my dobblebocks, but for a Double Hellesbock like this you can use any clean lager yeast with good results. I would mash this at 148°, with a 90min boil. Double the flavor and aroma hops over what you would use in an ale. Lagering mutes hop flavor and aroma. Don't forget the Diacetyl Rest. At srm 8 I'm sure they use a little melonoiden malt.